# Poset vs Set and Some Notations

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, order-theory

I apologize if I am splitting hairs here.

1. First of all, is a *poset* a *set*?

The official definition on my textbook says,

> If $X$ is a set and $R$ is an ordering on $X$, the pair $(X, R)$ is called an ordered set.

I mean a poset is a set **with a partial order**, whereas a set itself, by definition, does not have order. So I guess a poset is not a set? But if this is true, then I have another confusion:

2. There's a line from the book that says,

> A finite linearly ordered set has a (unique) largest element.

So if $x \in X$ and this $x$ is this largest element, is it ok to also write $x \in (X, R)$?

Answer (score 5):

1. $(X, R)$ is an [ordered pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair?wprov=sfti1). Which in set theory is a set.
2. You have $x \in X$. But you can’t say $x \in (X,R)$ as $(X,R)$ is indeed a set, but not a set that contains $x$.

Comment: Wouldn't a set be an *unordered pair*? Therefore, an ordered pair wouldn't be a set?

Comment: Please have a look at the Wikipedia link to see in detail what an ordered pair is.

Comment: @PrisonMike: In set theory *everything* is a set.

Answer (score 4):

A poset is the *combination* (ordered pair) of a set and a partial order $R$ on that same set.

So you could say that a poset $(X,R)$ has underlying set $X$ and an order $R$. Often the order is understood from context and we just say the poset $X$, which is not entirely correct formally. A poset is a set with extra structure, like a group, or a field, or a topological space, etc.

If a poset has a maximum, just say $x \in X$, not $x \in (X,R)$. It is an element of the underlying set, with special properties wrt the order $R$.